# Is there any way to supress or prevent python-mypy `Suspicious state` message

Tags: flycheck

When I open an empty Python file I get following warning message in the minibuffer. I added following into my init file:

`(require 'flycheck-mypy)`  //
`Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20200610.1809)`

```
Suspicious state from syntax checker python-mypy: Flycheck checker python-mypy returned 2, but its output contained no errors: config.py: error: Source file found twice under different module names: 'my_project.utils' and 'utils'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Try installing a more recent version of python-mypy, and please open a bug report 
if the issue persists in the latest release.
```

---

```bash
$ flake8 --version
3.8.3 (flake8-mypy: 17.8.0, mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.6.0, pyflakes:
2.2.0) CPython 3.7.5 on Linux
$ pip install -U mypy
$ pip freeze | grep mypy
flake8-mypy==17.8.0
mypy==0.780
```

Is there any way to prevent this `Suspicious state` message?

Comment: The package ```flycheck-mypy``` was deprecated two years ago, and embedded into ```flycheck```, so make some updates first.